# Title of linked question messed up when it includes MathJax

Tags: bug, status-review, mathjax, exact-duplicates

I've just flagged a question as duplicate ( it was [already deleted](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3073548/finding-ez-1-mid-z-1-z-2-where-z-1-and-z-2-are-independent-standard-n))
and the link to the [original one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2011019/exxy-for-i-i-d-normals) appears broken - not the link itself but the title:

[image]

If this helps, the source of the title of the linked question is:

```
$E(X|X>Y)$ for i.i.d normals?
```

Comment: Possibly related: [Why does not $a &lt; b$ render here?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13319)

Comment: Mmm I'm not sure. For one thing, the original MathJax does not use `&lt;` or `&gt;` it uses a plain `>`. Also, the title displays ok in the right sidebar, in the "Linked" questions section.

Comment: I encountered the same issue [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13752/conversation/issue-in-mathjax-rendering-in-comments).

Comment: As a workaround, the auto-inserted Comment for close-as-duplicate votes can be manually edited by "you the author" upon voting.  So the system created link can be modified to use a slightly different MathJax expression compatible with the MarkDown parser, if one wishes.

Comment: @hardmath Yes, but it turns out that the system then fails to recognize the auto-inserted comment as being auto-inserted. The next close vote re-generates the comment, along with another instance of the bug.